# best way to rename a database field to given pattern if it already exixts?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, file-upload

I have a database table that contains `id, filename, userId`

- id is unique identifier
- filename should also be unique
- table may contain >10000 records

> When a user uploads a file it should be entered in database with given
>   rules:

1. If there is no record with same filename, it should be *added as it is* (Ex. **foobar.pdf**)
2. If there is *record with same filename*, it should be *added as uploadedName(2).ext* (**foobar(2).pdf**)
3. If there are n records with same base filename (*foobar*), it should be *added as uploadedName(n+1).ext* (**foobar(20).pdf**)
4. Now if *foobar(2).pdf* is uploaded, it should be added as **foobar(2)(2).pdf** & so on

> This **pattern needs to be followed** because the file is already being
>   uploaded at client side using ajax before sending the details to
>   server and the file hosting service follows the above rules to name
>   the files.

---

***My solution:***

1. maintain a file that contains all the names and the number of times
   it has occurred.
2. if a filename that exists in file is entered, increase occurrence count and new name is generated, else add to it to file
3. if the new name generated is in database, add it to file and generate new name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you, since is an upload application, to do as follow

Create a column in your files table that store the original name of the file

Create another column to store a new generated name for the file, and this name would be some md5 or hash from the original plus the timestamp at the time of the upload, that ways you wouldn't have duplicated names.

Then when you upload your files you save then with this new name on the disk but show the original name to any application that requests it and if you need to download or stream it just get the saved hashed name from the database.

Comment: The naming pattern needs to be followed, because that is the only way i can keep track of the filenames uploaded on hosting service.

Comment: My suggestion is based on experience. I even migrate something near what you want to what I suggest. Do a piece of code for migrate the data is very simple, like a loop through the files that you have and code to rename it and store the new data on the database. But ok. I would recommend you to use pattern check with Regular expressions to achieve what you want.